# Resolve relative path

Tags: powershell

Given two arbitrary paths `base` and `destination`, I want to find the minimal relative path from `base` to `destination`.

My current implementation is:

```
Push-Location $base
try {
    return (Resolve-Path -relative $destination)
} finally {
    Pop-Location
}
```

However, this does not fulfill the requirement of being minimal. For instance, given the two paths `C:\A\B\C` and `C:\A\B`, I'm getting `..\..\B`, as result, which should actually be `..` instead. It's worth to note that if `destination` is a file, this is indeed minimal, but not for folders.

I would be glad not to do something like truncating manually or stuff like that.

Comment: So regex/string manipulation is not allowed?

Comment: So if `$base='C:\A\B\C'; $destination='C:\A\B'` then  return value is `..\..\B`? But you get the same value from `Resolve-Path -relative ..`, don't you? Two consecutive periods (`..`) used as a directory _component_ in a path _represent_ the parent of the current directory (and _not_ a valid relative path, **strictly said**?)

Comment: @JosefZ Well, that's because those are 2 representations of the same relative path. And given a path (whether absolute or relative), adding `\..` represents a relative path, no? Maybe I misunderstood you. If so, care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetRelative($base, $destination) {
    $baseUri = [System.Uri]$($base + '/')
    $destinationUri = [System.Uri]$($destination + '/')
    $relativePath = $baseUri.MakeRelativeUri($destinationUri).OriginalString.TrimEnd('/').Replace('/', '\');
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($relativePath)) { return "." }
    else { return $relativePath }
}
```

Comment: This breaks down when `base` is in a different folder, example for `base` and `direction` values of `C:\A` and `C:\B\C` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($base -eq $destination) {
    return "."
}

if ($destination.StartsWith($base)) {
    # destination is inside base

    $baseRE = [regex]::Escape($base)
    return $destination -replace "$baseRE\\?", ""
} else {
    # destination is inside a parent of base

    if (!$base.StartsWith($destination)) {
        # destination is a file

        $fileDir = Split-Path $destination
        $destRE = [regex]::Escape($fileDir)

        $relativePathToFile = $base -replace "$destRE\\?", "" -replace "([^\\]+)", ".."
        $fileName = Split-Path $destination -Leaf

        return Join-Path $relativePathToFile $fileName
    }

    $destRE = [regex]::Escape($destination)
    return $base -replace "$destRE\\?", "" -replace "([^\\]+)", ".."
}
```

I guess this doesn't fall within "truncating manually or stuff like that."?